# encapsulating javascript inside a namespace

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to encapsulate my javascript inside a namespace like this:

```
MySpace = {

   SomeGlobal : 1,
   A: function () { ... }, 
   B: function () { ....; MySpace.A(); .... },
   C: function () { MySpace.SomeGlobal = 2;.... }
}
```

Now imagine that instead of a few lines of code, I have about 12K lines of javascript with hundreds of functions and about 60 globals. I already know how to convert my code into a namespace but I'm wondering if there's a quicker way of doing it than going down 12K lines of code and adding `MySpace.` all over the place.

Please let me know if there's a faster way of doing this.
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I fixed your code example since it would have never run the way you had it typed up.

Comment: Yes, thanks for fixing it; just noticed after you had made the edit. Any suggestion on how to make the conversion?

Comment: Namespace is not a really good solution. Try wrapping your code with a closure and export public definitions.

Comment: Agree with @Florent. Do you want your code to be able to access every variable you're trying to declare as `MySpace.`?

Comment: What's the pros/con of wrapping vs. namespacing?

Comment: @Florent: can you show with code what this would look?

Comment: 12k lines of js code is a code smell. The best way is to refactor the whole thing breaking it down in to smaller manageable chunks of code that do a particular task. It's not the fastest way but it will be far easier to manage and maintain in the future. Interesting article here (http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/06/04/anders-hejlsberg-is-right-you-cannot-maintain-large-programs-in-javascript/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+LosTechies+%28LosTechies%29)

Comment: When wrapping your code you can easily convert it to AMD. If you do it well, your code will be easier to maintain and more readable. This is a good read: [Writing Modular JavaScript](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/).

Comment: I'd also recommend using something like require.js for module loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to wrap up the namespace like so. The flexibility is huge, and we can even separate different modules of the MySpace namespace in separate wrappers if we wanted too. You will still have to add some sort of `_self.` reference infront of everything, but at least this way you can change the entire name of the namespace very quickly if need be.

You can see how with this method you can even call _self.anotherFunc() from the 1st module, and you'll get to the second one.

```
(function (MySpace, $, undefined) {

    var _self = MySpace; // create a self-reference
    _self.test = function () { 
        alert('we got here!'); 
        _self.anotherFunc(); // testing to see if we can get the 2nd module
    };

    _self = MySpace; // reassign everything just incase

}(window.MySpace = window.MySpace || {}, jQuery));

$(function () { 

    MySpace.test(); // call module 1
    MySpace.callOtherModule(); // call module 2

});

// Here we will create a seperate Module to the MySpace namespace
(function (MySpace, $, undefined) {
    var _self = MySpace; // create a self-reference

    _self.callOtherModule = function () {
        alert('we called the 2nd module!');    
    };

    _self.anotherFunc = function () { 
        alert('We got to anotherFunc from the first module, even by using _self.anotherFunc()!'); 
    };
    _self = MySpace; // reassign everything just incase

}(window.MySpace = window.MySpace || {}, jQuery));​
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pbXLB/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a `function` body around your existing code to use as scope, hiding everything from global - this will allow you to do internal calls without pasting `Namespace.` prefix everywhere, neatly hide things you don't want everyone else to see, and will require minimal changes as well.

After that, decide what functions you want to "export" for everyone and assign them to properties of object you want to use as "namespace".